# How to show a custom taxonomy using a custom template

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I've been playing around the custom taxonomy and custom post types. I've been able to get the post type working fine, with my slug as I need. 
However, creating a taxonomy page (e.g. taxonomy-????) I receive a 404 error page.

I'm sure I did something wrong, and this is possibly due the fact both my slug lines are the same.

```
'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'faqs/archivio' ),
```

However, the custom taxonomy URL is correct in both cases, so this could be due to the fact the page taxonomy-[customtaxonomy].php file, but I have created one.

I have also forced WP to refresh the taxonomy so I can't figure out what's the problem. Any help?

Comment: Have you flushed your permalinks? What is the full code for registering your taxonomy?

Comment: You can't have the same slug for two different object types, one rewrite rule will always take precedence over the other.

Comment: Hi @Milo thanks for this. So how can I add a taxonomy whose URLs are nested under a specific structure? Can you by any chance create a piece of code on pastebin or somewhere else?